# Availability tests: is it possibile to HTTP-ping an endpoint with AAD enabled?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-application-insights, availability

To better understand and then implement it in our projects I've created a **Function App** with 3 endpoints (source code in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/gsscoder/ff78ee1ec22eeaa3afcb43274af04956)) and configured 6 **Availability Tests** (of kind **Ping Test**):

```
oktest: https://myfuncname.azurewebsites.net/api/ok (parse dependent requests = false)
oktest2: https://myfuncname.azurewebsites.net/api/ok (parse dependent requests = true)
badtest: https://myfuncname.azurewebsites.net/api/bad (parse dependent requests = false)
badtest2: https://myfuncname.azurewebsites.net/api/bad (parse dependent requests = true)
errtest: https://myfuncname.azurewebsites.net/api/err (parse dependent requests = false)
errtest2: https://myfuncname.azurewebsites.net/api/err (parse dependent requests = true)
```

The Function App is configured with **AAD** using Client ID and Allowed Token Audiences.

```
/ok returns 200 content OK
/bad returns 400 content BAD
/err returns 500
```

Testing Azure the endpoints with Postman (using a valid **Bearer Token**) produces expected results as in local hosting environment.

I'm expecting to have 100% ok success in `oktest` and `oktest2` and 100% of failures in other tests.

I'm getting these results:

```
oktest: success 21 fail 0
oktest2: success 17 fail 0
badtest: success 20 fail 2
badtest2: success 17 fail 0
errtest: success 21 fail 1
errtest2: success 17 fail 0
```

Then I set authentication to **Allow Anonymous** and I get these results after some cycle:

```
oktest: success 31 fail 0
oktest2: success 36 fail 0
badtest: success 29 fail 9
badtest2: success 25 fail 8
errtest: success 28 fail 8
errtest2: success 24 fail 7
```

It's quite clear that first authentication settings prevented endpoints to be *HTTP-pinged*. Is this possible to keep AAD authentication or we've to rethink our network architecture?

Any help or suggestion will be very appreciated!

Regards,
Giacomo S. S.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've understood the situation.

When **Allow Anonymous** is enabled the HTTP-ping correctly fails in 'badtest':

[image]

When **AAD authentication** is enabled the HTTP-ping returns a success cause the
Availability Test is able to authenticate and than returns **200 OK** for that (a successful authentication):

[image]

Looking these details it's possible explain any single result.

My conclusion: **Availability Tests are more oriented to test web pages and not REST services.**

Confirmations can be found in MS docs.

If anyone have something to add, I'm very interested!